# What's the simplest way to add subscription/payment/premium features to a flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, payment, subscription

I have finished the core functionality of the freemium version of my flutter app which I plan to publish to the Play Store. I now want to add an in-app subscription method, digital payment, and also way for the users to access premium features if they have a subscription.

What is the simplest way/format/method of doing this? What tools do I need and what are the typical steps. I want it straightforward, and my goal for now is to publish to the Play Store for Android.

Essentially what is the typical format/logic/timeline for doing this and implementing it?

I have not tried anything specific yet. I am starting to establish my Google Play Console account though. My Firebase authentication is already built and finished for standard freemium users.

Comment: revenuecat and purchases_flutter package